# My HTML5 canvas game keeps blinking in between frames

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, game-development

I've started working on an HTML5 RPG canvas game recently, and decided to make a "text-box" sort of thing, but when once I programmed it, it started blinking between the blue and text box every other frame. What could have caused this?

Code: https://github.com/Codezters/RPG-Game-1

Important Code (I think most of the player movement stuff is irrelevant though):

```
  function update() {
        if (realm == 'overworld') {
            cc.fillStyle='blue';
            cc.fillRect(0,0,c.width,c.height);
            cc.drawImage(bob, x, y);

            // Player Walk Animations 

            if (direction == 'up' && idleness == false) {
                if (walkstage > 0 && walkstage <4) {
                    document.getElementById("source").src = "IdleMoveUP1.png"
                }
                else if (walkstage > 3 &&  walkstage < 7) {
                    document.getElementById("source").src = "IdleUP.png"
                }
                else if (walkstage > 6 && walkstage < 10) {
                    document.getElementById("source").src = "IdleMoveUP2.png"
                }
            }
            else if (direction == 'right' && idleness == false) {
                if (walkstage > 0 && walkstage <4) {
                    document.getElementById("source").src = "IdleMoveRIGHT1.png"
                }
                else if (walkstage > 3 &&  walkstage < 7) {
                    document.getElementById("source").src = "IdleRIGHT.png"
                }
                else if (walkstage > 6 && walkstage < 10) {
                    document.getElementById("source").src = "IdleMoveRIGHT2.png"
                }
            }
            else if (direction == 'left' && idleness == false) {
                if (walkstage > 0 && walkstage <4) {
                    document.getElementById("source").src = "IdleMoveLEFT1.png"
                }
                else if (walkstage > 3 &&  walkstage < 7) {
                    document.getElementById("source").src = "IdleLEFT.png"
                }
                else if (walkstage > 6 && walkstage < 10) {
                    document.getElementById("source").src = "IdleMoveLEFT2.png"
                }
            }
            else if (direction == 'down' && idleness == false) {
                if (walkstage > 0 && walkstage <4) {
                    document.getElementById("source").src = "IdleMoveDOWN1.png"
                }
                else if (walkstage > 3 &&  walkstage < 7) {
                    document.getElementById("source").src = "IdleDOWN.png"
                }
                else if (walkstage > 6 && walkstage < 10) {
                    document.getElementById("source").src = "IdleMoveDOWN2.png"
                }
            }        
            if (idleframe == 8) {
                if (direction == 'down') {
                    document.getElementById("source").src = "IdleDOWN.png"
                    idleframe = 0;
                    idleness = true;
                }
                else if (direction == 'up') {
                    document.getElementById("source").src = "IdleUP.png"
                    idleframe = 0;
                    idleness = true;
                }
                else if (direction == 'right') {
                    document.getElementById("source").src = "IdleRIGHT.png"
                    idleframe = 0;
                    idleness = true;
                }
                else if (direction == 'left') {
                    document.getElementById("source").src = "IdleLEFT.png"
                    idleframe = 0;
                    idleness = true;
                }
                if (talking == true) {
                    if (wordcount != textBoxTest.length) {
                        cc.drawImage(textBox, 0, 400);
                        cc.fillStyle = "white";
                        console.log("this is working")
                        cc.fillText(counted, 0, 100);
                        counted += textBoxTest[wordcount]
                        wordcount++;
                    }
                    else if (EnterToggle == true) {
                        EnterToggle = false;
                        talking = false;
                    }
```

Game so far: https://codezters.github.io/RPG-Game-1/

Solution:

I didn't need to clear the canvas when nothing was happening, so I made it clear less frequently and the problem was fixed.

Comment: Clicked on the "game so far" - saw not skippable preroll credits (at least not intuitively) - closed it and ran away. This has nothing to do with your bug, but is just a general tip.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the tip.

Comment: I've fixed it so that you can skip through the opening crawl using the ENTER key.

Comment: You should seriously consider using a gaming engine for this, there are plenty out there: https://github.com/collections/javascript-game-engines

Answer (score 2):

The HTML is completely wrong for a start, with tags in the wrong places and obsolete elements. I mean no offense, we all have to start somewhere, but you should complete a basic course in HTML and JavaScript before attempting this. MDN is a great place to start.

You're changing the `src` attribute of img tags, you shouldn't be doing that at all. Use a different Image object for each file and make your code choose which image to draw instead. This ensures all images are loaded once before the game starts and not every time you change it. Loading can take place asynchronously and cause errors where the image is not ready to be drawn yet when you try to.

You also have this code:

```
window.onload= function() {
    c=document.getElementById('gc');
    document.addEventListener("keydown",keyPush)
    cc=c.getContext('2d');
    setInterval(update,1000/30);
};
```

Since you run update through `setInterval`, you both update and draw the game 33 times per second. You should have an independent function which takes care of drawing which is called with `requestAnimationFrame(draw)`. This will make sure the browser only draws frames when it can, and skips drawing when the computer is having trouble keeping up. Go read the documentation on [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) for more info.